# Split multiple csv files in chunks based on condition

Tags: r, split

I have 400+ quite large csv files (~ million rows) having all a similar structure :

1. A long header of which I only need the 2nd and 3rd rows
2. A first time serie (always preceded by 'Target1')
3. A second time serie (always preceded by 'Target2')

Here is an example of data :

```
#multiple rows of header#
Target 1
Timestamp,X,Y,Z
1553972886851,0.017578,-0.003052,-0.971375
1553972886851,0.017883,-0.003662,-0.980408
1553972886851,0.016418,-0.003174,-0.977295
1553972886999,0.017151,-0.002808,-0.978088
1553972886999,0.016785,-0.003113,-0.977051
1553972886999,0.017883,-0.002197,-0.975830
1553972887096,0.017517,-0.003113,-0.976624
1553972887096,0.017883,-0.003113,-0.977966
1553972887096,0.017883,-0.002869,-0.978210
1553972887243,0.017151,-0.003113,-0.976135
1553972887243,0.018250,-0.003235,-0.975647
1553972887243,0.017273,-0.002991,-0.976257
1553972887340,0.018372,-0.003235,-0.977722
1553972887340,0.017761,-0.003235,-0.978027
Target 2
Timestamp,X,Y,Z
1553972886753,-0.411585,0.072409,-0.849848
1553972886753,-0.339177,-0.053354,-0.556402
1553972886753,-0.411585,-0.262957,-0.483994
1553972886855,-0.506860,-0.057165,-0.472561
1553972886855,-0.499238,-0.007622,-0.529726
1553972886855,-0.472561,-0.041921,-0.560213
1553972887002,-0.510671,-0.083841,-0.480183
1553972887002,-0.525915,-0.057165,-0.480183
1553972887002,-0.544969,-0.038110,-0.522104
1553972887098,-0.510671,-0.030488,-0.510671
1553972887098,-0.529726,-0.026677,-0.525915
1553972887098,-0.510671,-0.068598,-0.518293
```

I need to split each csv files in those 3 parts and name them accordingly.

I managed to do step 1) and step 3) but struggle for step 2).

Here is what I did for step 3) :

```
fileNames <- basename(list.files(path = ".", all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = TRUE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE))
extension <- "txt"
fileNumbers <- seq(fileNames)

for (fileNumber in fileNumbers) {

  newFileName <-  paste("Target2-", 
                        sub(paste("\\.", extension, sep = ""), "", fileNames[fileNumber]), 
                        ".", extension, sep = "")

  # read old data:

  Lines <- readLines(fileNames[fileNumber])
  ix <- which(Lines == "Target2")

  sample <- read.csv(fileNames[fileNumber],
                     header = TRUE,
                     sep = ",", skip= ix)

  # write old data to new files:
  write.table(sample, 
              newFileName,
              append = FALSE,
              quote = FALSE,
              sep = ",",
              row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = TRUE)

}
```

I'm quite sure this is not the most straightforward approach and I can't get the data comprised between Target 1 and Target 2 using this approach. Also, this is super slow and I was wondering it there could be a more memory efficient approach ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = function(filename) {
  cat("\nprocessing", filename, "...")
  x = readLines(con = filename) 
  idx = grepl("^Target", x)
  x = split(x[!idx], cumsum(idx)[!idx])[-1]
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    write.table(
      x = x[[i]], 
      file = sub("\\.csv", paste0("_", i, ".csv"), filename),
      append =FALSE,
      row.names = FALSE,
      quote = FALSE, 
      col.names = FALSE)
  }))
}

files = list.files(path = "path/to/files", pattern = ".+\\.csv$")
lapply(files, foo)
```

Comment: Can you provide and explanation?

Comment: Thanks, the output looks correct but I am not sure that I understand all of it